# click in datatable to filter other charts (dc.js)

Tags: dc.js

I need to filter other charts when I click a row in the datatable.

I did

```
my_table.on('pretransition', function (table) {
     table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
          .on('click',function(d){
                table.filter(d.key)
                dc.redrawAll();
           })
});
```

but nothing happens in the other charts.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### If the table dimension is a dimension...

The data that ordinarily populates a data table is the raw rows from the original data set, not key/value pairs.

So it is likely that `d.key` is undefined.

I'd advise you first to stick

```
console.log(d)
```

into your click handler to see what your data looks like, to make sure `d.key` is valid.

Second, remember that a chart filters through its dimension. So you will need to pass a value to `table.filter()` that is a valid key for your dimension, and then it will filter out all rows for which the key is different. This may not be just the one row that you chose.

Typically a table dimension is chosen for the way it orders the values for the rows. You might actually want to filter some other dimension. But hopefully this is enough to get you started.

#### But what if the the table dimension is a group?

The above technique will only work if your table takes a crossfilter dimension as its dimension. If, as in the fiddle you linked in the comments, you're using a group as your dimension, that object has no `.filter()` method, so the `table.filter()` method won't do anything.

If you only need to filter the one item that was clicked, you could just do

```
foodim.filter(d.key)
```

This has an effect but it's not that useful.

If you need the toggle functionality used in dc's ordinal charts, you'll need to simulate it. It's not all that complicated:

```
// global
var filterKeys = [];

// inside click event

                if(filterKeys.indexOf(d.key)===-1)
                  filterKeys.push(d.key);
                else
                  filterKeys = filterKeys.filter(k => k != d.key);
                if(filterKeys.length === 0)
                  foodim.filter(null);
                else 
                  foodim.filterFunction(function(d) {
                    return filterKeys.indexOf(d) !== -1;
                  })
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/kfmfkLj0/9/

Comment: Hello, i'm sorry for my english.

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion, if I get the key of the data when testing with console.log (d.key) that corresponds to the key of the dimension of the datatable.
I wish that when selecting that key, affect the graphics associated with the data, which have other dimensions, but with crossfilter are associated.

Comment: It worked for me once I chose a field from `d` which was appropriate for the dimension. Hard to say what's going wrong in your app without seeing a working example, or at least some more code + example data.

Comment: I see, you're using a group for your dimension, and groups don't filter, dimensions do. I've added a note to my answer.