# dc.js table -- Select row(s), highlight onclick and apply filter for Crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Using this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957203/click-in-datatable-to-filter-other-charts-dc-js) as a starting point. Thanks to Gordon's solution, the selectable table is built and filters but I am interested in highlighting the row once clicked and allowing for multiple selections(filters applied).

Thinking that one could utilize the filterKeys array that Gordon describes in his solution but not sure how to apply the highlighting effects and remove them.

Comment: Hmm, the answer is on here somewhere. IIRC the question you linked was an early iteration and later on I helped people implement highlighting and multiple selection.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon!  As always your solutions are solid. I've upvoted that solution and the question.